# I guess I found a typo on android documentation

Tags: android, code-documentation

I think I found a typo on Android Developer Documentation Page.

This is the normal documentation I think:

[image]

This is the weird part of it:
[image]

Sorry for the links, I can't upload a picture since I'm newcomer to this site.

The documentation says

`a CellSignalStrengthNr instance. This value will never be null.`

but the return type is:

`CellSignalStrength`

Am I asking a question for sure thing?
Or the Documentation Page is wrong?

Comment: You can click on the `CellSignalStrengthNr` link to check what is it. Actually, `CellSignalStrengthNr` is extended from `CellSignalStrength` class. So it's not an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct link to the docs is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/CellInfoNr

The way to get docs corrected is to report the error to the author, not by posting a question on StackOverflow.

The link for doc errors is https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697

Comment: I just wanted to know whether I'm wrong or not.
Thank you for your kindness. (The links)